# Linking MVC4 Models By ID

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Woke up  yesterday wondering what all the fuss with MVC was about. So I found out and wow it's nice and stuff like that.

I'm used to using one related Linq to Sql DataContext DB in ASP.NET projects.

```
 //Some ASP.NET Page Codebehind
 DataContext dbEntire = new DataContext()
```

With MVC4 with the Entity framework you make the model and it creates a DB for you.

```
 //Models/Article/Article.cs
public class ArticleDBContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
} 
public class Article
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Submitted{ get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
}
```

Author and Category are seperate Models.

But how do you set up all the database relations..  One to many, etc. etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ArticleDBContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
} 

public class Article
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public DateTime Submitted{ get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

Go through some tutorials on Entity Framework Code First.

[EF Code First and MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

[EF getting started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907)